# Outputing multidimensional array - many levels

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a way to output a multidimensional array as a simple table.

I got it by processing xml available here `http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=adam` with the simple function

```
function convertXmlObjToArr($obj) { 
$json = json_encode($obj);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

return $array;
```

}

and got an array

```
   array(1){ ["CompleteSuggestion"]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["suggestion"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["data"]=>
          string(12) "adam sandler"
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["suggestion"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["data"]=>
          string(11) "adam levine"
        }
      }
      ["num_queries"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["int"]=>
          string(8) "33200000"
        }
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["suggestion"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["data"]=>
          string(12) "adam carolla"
        }
      }
      ["num_queries"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["int"]=>
          string(7) "5570000"
        }
      }
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      ["suggestion"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["data"]=>
          string(12) "adam lambert"
        }
      }
      ["num_queries"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["int"]=>
          string(8) "45400000"
        }
      }
    }
    [4]=>
    array(1) {
      ["suggestion"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["data"]=>
          string(17) "adam sandler died"
        }
      }
    }
    [5]=>
    array(2) {
      ["suggestion"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["data"]=>
          string(19) "adam sandler movies"
        }
      }
      ["num_queries"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["int"]=>
          string(8) "43600000"
        }
      }
    }
    [6]=>
    array(2) {
      ["suggestion"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["data"]=>
          string(13) "adam morrison"
        }
      }
      ["num_queries"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["int"]=>
          string(8) "13800000"
        }
      }
    }
    [7]=>
    array(2) {
      ["suggestion"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["data"]=>
          string(10) "adams golf"
        }
      }
      ["num_queries"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["int"]=>
          string(8) "30500000"
        }
      }
    }
    [8]=>
    array(2) {
      ["suggestion"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["data"]=>
          string(10) "adam yauch"
        }
      }
      ["num_queries"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["int"]=>
          string(8) "19700000"
        }
      }
    }
    [9]=>
    array(2) {
      ["suggestion"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["data"]=>
          string(9) "adam west"
        }
      }
      ["num_queries"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["int"]=>
          string(9) "137000000"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I would like to output it and face 2 problems:

1. How do I "dig into" the relevant information ("data" and "int") in an array structured like this?  So far I was dealing with much simpler arrays (not so "deep").
   I am trying to for it via foreach loop

```
foreach($googleKeywords->CompleteSuggestion as $suggestion){
```

`echo"{$this->suggestion->data}";
         }`

but keep getting "Trying to get property of non-object" error.

1. As you notice some of the data is not complete - there is a name in "data" but not corresponding "int"... would be there a way to echo "no data" whether "int" is not set?

All the best,

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks,

The final code that worked involved nested loops and is as follows:

```
<pre>foreach($keywords as $suggestion){
 foreach ($suggestion as $finalSuggestion){
   echo "<p>".$finalSuggestion['suggestion']['@attributes']['data']."</p>";
   echo $finalSuggestion['num_queries']['@attributes']['data']."<br/>";
    if (array_key_exists('num_queries', $finalSuggestion)) {
    echo "<p> ".$finalSuggestion['num_queries']['@attributes']['int']." </p>";
    }
    else
        {
        echo "<p>no data</p> ";
    }
     }

}
</pre>
```

PS. Sorry for the awful formatting of the code , still not sure how to do it properly here.... I usually just put < pre> but it goes wild now....

Answer (score 1):

You could try this **(Code updated)**:

```
foreach($googleKeywords['CompleteSuggestion'] as $suggestion){
    if (count($suggestion) == 2) {
        echo $suggestion['suggestion']['@attributes']['data'];
        echo $suggestion['num_queries']['@attributes']['int'];
    }
}
```

This should at least give you in idea on how to access the elements of your array.

I'll leave it up to you to format the output.

The `if` statement checks that all data is set (you expect 2 items, both data and int). You could have an `else{}` section that echoes "data not set". The `for` loop is necessary because you don't know how many elements, and this style of `for` loop works that out for you. It will loop over all the elements in the array, whether there is only 1, or 9, or whatever. If there are zero elements in the array, the `for` loop will be skipped.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @user1404632 , when I remove the if statementthis code returns only the value of the first element, but the foreach loop is still there. I do not want to use a "for" loop because what if the array is larger than 9 elements.... Any thaughts?

Comment: Sorry about that, I had a bug in my code (now fixed). I've also added some more comments to the answer to explain what is going on.